# How to split column without delimiter pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have this csv-file, where the first column is the date in this format: YYYYMMDD. I don't need the YYYY. I would like to delete the YYYY part and keep the MMDD part. But there is no delimiter between those. I've tried a couple of things, but nothing worked. Except for this method, which loops through each row and deletes the year, but this takes ages for my file with more than a million rows.

This is my loop, but I can't seem to find a way to do it for all rows in one go.

```
def drop_year(row):
    print(row[0])
    data.iloc[row[0]] = str(row[0])[4:]
[drop_year(row) for row in data.iterrows()]
```

Comment: Could you try `data[:,4:]`?

Comment: Or maybe something like `df.Date.str[4:]`?

Comment: A column of data like data["YYYYMMDD"] with YYYYMMDD as the header of the column is not seen as a string, so I can't do .str on it.

Comment: What is the data type of the column?

Comment: Could you post an example tha shows how it looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, thank you all for your help.

```
data["YYYYMMDD"] = (data.YYYYMMDD.astype(str).str)[4:]
```